# Find and replace text in date format with current date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace a date in a string with current date.

Date is not fixed so I cannot tell VBA which date to replace.

It's written something like:
01-Jun-21_Detailed_Summary
02-Jun-21_Plannig

Date format is fixed.

I tried

```vb
Dim TD, YD as String
TD=Format(Date,"DD-MMM-YY")
YD=Format(Date -1,"DD-MMM-YY")
Cells.Replace What:=YD, Replacement:=TD
```

I have success in but I have to tell VBA to subtract number of days so it can search and replace which is quite lengthy now considering the data and knowledge I have.

I am looking for a code in which all selected dates should get replaced with the help of format only.

Comment: Do you want to replace all dates with today's date?  And are all the dates part of a text string and also all in the format of dd-mmm-yy?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace all the dates in specific cell with current date. Format is fixed DD-MMM-YY

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use Regular expression to determine the date string, and replace with the formatted todays date.

In the code below, the result is written next to the original; but you can write it anyplace, including replacing the original

```
Option Explicit
Sub replWithTodayDate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range
    Dim v As Variant, i As Long
    Dim RE As Object, repl As String
    
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
With ws
    Set r = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'Copy of the data on the worksheet
End With

'read into vba array for faster processing
v = r

'Use regex to make the replacements
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\b\d\d-(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d\d"
    .ignorecase = True
    repl = Format(Date, "dd-MMM-yy")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        v(i, 1) = RE.Replace(v(i, 1), repl)
    Next i
End With

'write back to the worksheet
r.Offset(0, 1) = v
    
End Sub
```

[image]

### Date in dd-mmm-yy pattern

```
\b\d\d-(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d\d
```

Options: Case insensitive

- [Assert position at a word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`
- [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`
- [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`
- [Match the character “-” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)`

  - [Match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Jan`

    - [Match the character string “Jan” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Jan`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Feb`

    - [Match the character string “Feb” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Feb`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Mar`

    - [Match the character string “Mar” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Mar`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Apr`

    - [Match the character string “Apr” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Apr`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `May`

    - [Match the character string “May” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `May`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Jun`

    - [Match the character string “Jun” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Jun`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Jul`

    - [Match the character string “Jul” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Jul`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Aug`

    - [Match the character string “Aug” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Aug`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Sep`

    - [Match the character string “Sep” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Sep`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Oct`

    - [Match the character string “Oct” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Oct`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Nov`

    - [Match the character string “Nov” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Nov`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Dec`

    - [Match the character string “Dec” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Dec`
- [Match the character “-” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
- [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`
- [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)